# How to find all files that not belong to any repository?

Tags: repository, debian

In my Debian system I have files that not belong to any repository, they are mine or from compilated programs installed with 'make install'. How can I find all files that not belong to any repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that with *files not belonging to any repository* you really mean

> files that do not belong to a package installed on your system

the following script will check whether a given file (full path) belongs to a package, and if not, print its name (if the file belongs to a pkg *or* does not exist it will remain silent).

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -e "$1" ]; then
 dpkg -S "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "$1"
fi
```

if you save the above as (e.g.) `/tmp/checkindeb` and make it executable, then you can run

```
$ find / -type f -exec /tmp/checkindeb \{\} \;
```

and it will print all files on your system that were not installed by a package.

note: the above test is *very* slow.

you can speedup the process by:

- excluding all files in `/dev/`, `/sys` and `/proc` and other pseudo-filesystems that do not contain any real (and/or persistent) files.
- excluding all files in `/usr/local`, `/home`, `/tmp` and other well known directories a package will *never* install files into (esp. '/home` is notorious, as it usually contains lots of files and all of them owned by the user)
- exluding all files on network shares (NFS, CIFS,...)
- generating a list of all files installed by all packages and compare it to a list of all files installed on your computer.

something like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
DEBFILES=$(mktemp)
ALLFILES=$(mktemp)

dpkg -L $(dpkg --get-selections | cut -f1) | while read f; do
  test -f "${f}" && echo "${f}"
done | sort -u > "${DEBFILES}"

find / \(                                                          \
      -wholename /home -o -wholename /tmp -o -wholename /usr/local \
      -o -wholename /sys -o -wholename /proc -o -wholename /dev    \
   \) -prune                                                       \
   -o -type f -print                                               \
| sort -u "${ALLFILES}"

diff "${DEBFILES}" "${ALLFILES}"
```

you might have to run the command as root to have proper permissions to list all files.